# Multiple Level Discriminator Mapping Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I've got a 3 level table inheritance, and when I attempt to insert into the database, Doctrine is sensible enough to insert at the lowest level, and the highest level - *but not at the middle level*.

I'm unsure whether what we're attempting to do is properly supported by Doctrine - the lack of examples on the docs and Google suggest that it might not be. If it is supported, what could I be doing wrong?

EDIT:

A slightly better explanation:

I have 3 tables (A, B and C). I've got a discriminator map such that C extends B, and B extends A. When I try an insert into Table A then Doctrine is clever enough to insert into C and A, but *not* B.

Comment: Consider adding some more information to your question.  In particular, explaining what middle level means.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple discrimination levels while using Doctrine2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932505/multiple-discrimination-levels-while-using-doctrine2)